# Ethernet Controller - Signals

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, clock, ethernet, phy

I was going through the datasheet of this [Ethernet controller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002416A.pdf) IC.

I see that the pins are different than that of a Normal Ethernet PHY.

Usually PHY has Ethernet Tx and Rx signals and has the MII/RMII or other MII interface pins.
But seeing the block diagram of this ethernet controller, it seems to be similar to the block diagram of a PHY, but there are no MII/RMII signal pins. There are only Bi directional IO pins. Why is that or what sort of interface or protocol is this?

Can someone  please tell me the difference between this IC and what it does when compared to a normal PHY transceiver. Just got confused because a PHY and this IC seem to have the same block diagram but this IC has no MII interface pins.

Comment: You're trying to compare this IC to a "normal PHY", but it's not a "normal PHY". In fact it's not a PHY at all - its a combined PHY, MAC & parallel host bus interface.

Comment: Oh, just wanted to understand why does a person use this IC? Like, when do we use this Ethernet Controller IC and when do we use an Ethernet PHY transceiver?

Comment: why did you not ask that at the begining?

Comment: I apologize for that.

Comment: You use this chip if you need Ethernet but you don't have it unless you add this chip.

Comment: @Justme, unable to understand. Could you please explain a bit more

Comment: If your CPU does not have built in Ethernet controller, then you need to add an external Ethernet controller.

Comment: Oh, so this Ethernet controller has internal PHY, which also connects to the internal MAC and these MAC signal information is provided to the host processor for processing. Am I right?

Comment: @Newbie yes. It also has two builtin FIFO buffers (or something like them) so that your microcontroller doesn't have to urgently process the packet exactly when it arrives

Comment: The first page of the datasheet outlines all of this.